# Erro "does not appear to be a git repository"

Tags: git, github

```
Informania 3229-6725@DESKTOP-VD1D35H MINGW64 ~/Documents/CursoJS/git (main)
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/Hiltonr/Projetogit.git
error: remote origin already exists.

Informania 3229-6725@DESKTOP-VD1D35H MINGW64 ~/Documents/CursoJS/git (main)
$ git push -u origin main
fatal: '––––––––––––––––' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro erro diz que o "remote origin" já foi configurado.
Se você executar `git remote show origin` ou `git remote -v`, verá a url que foi inserida.

Quando você tentou executar o `git push`, ele recusou por causa que o origin não é um repositório git. Você provavelmente colocou o url errado.

Use o comando `git remote remove origin` para remover origin e re-configure o link do repositório com o `git remote add origin`.

#### Referências

- [Documentação de git-remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote/pt_BR)

Comment: o seu repositório é o https://github.com/Hiltonr/meuprojetogit , não Projetogit.

Comment: DEU CERTO ^^ MUITO OBRIGADO, RENATO